# Elastic Search Querying - how to group the results and perform operations on results

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, aggregation, facet

I am very much new to Elastic Search. So need help in writing queries for use cases in Elastic Search.

We have a scenario where we need to perform operation on results of query and also do some grouping on data.
For example, Consider below sample use case.

Document has fields and values like below :

```
documentId : 1284che3t3bdf2
playerName : John
playerId : 123456
timestamp : X milliseconds (long value)
status : START_SPRINT

documentId : 45645bf6cxf3674
playerName : John
playerId : 123456
timestamp : Y milliseconds (long value)
status : END_SPRINT
```

Now we have to retrieve the time taken by player John to complete the sprint.

ie., we need to get time difference (Y-X) for
    playerName:John

We also need average time taken for all players to complete sprint. 
Looking at documentation, looks like using aggregations and filters we can achieve this.

Appreciate if any help with queries or any pointers to write these queries.

Could write below query so far using scripted metric aggregations :
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html

```
    {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "aggs": {
            "average": {
                "scripted_metric": {
                    "init_script" : "_agg['timestamps'] = []",
                    "map_script" : "if (doc['status'].value == \"END\") {      
                                      _agg.timestamps.add(doc.timestamp.value) 
                                    } else {
                                     _agg.timestamps.add(-1 * doc.timestamp.value) }",
                    "combine_script" : "total = 0;
                                        average = 0;
                                        for (t in _agg.timestamps) { total += t }; 
                                        average = total/_agg.timestamps.length;
                                       return average",
                    "reduce_script" : "average = 0; 
                                      for (a in _aggs) { average += a }; 
                                      return average"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does this have to do with MapReduce? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am able to write a facet query with terms so far. Started trying queries using metrics aggregations.

Comment: Please update with the facet query you wrote!

Comment: Updated with query i could write so far above. i'm getting some parse error as of now, Hope I'm going in the right direction. Please advise.

Comment: you are kidding with me, right? you have just copied the example and pasted here!